# GWT logging in Production mode with Console Handler

Tags: gwt

I have enabled GWT logging with ConsoleHandler as shown below.

```
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
   <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO"/> 
   <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/> 
   <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
```

Because of this I also see a logging window appearing on application page and logs in console of the browser as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging) which is obvious.

How do I disable the window appearing on my application and have only browser console on in production mode?

Is it that we have to disable the ConsoleHandler? Or may be I have to use SimpleRemoteLogHandler when in production mode?

There is also a FirebugLogHandler but limited to Firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>` most log handlers are enabled already, including the `popupHandler` which is responsible for the window popping up.

You'll want to disable all those you don't want/need rather than enable the one you want.

See https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/logging/LoggingDisabled.gwt.xml#132

---

As a side note, `gwt.logging.logLevel` already defaults to `INFO` and `gwt.logging.enabled` is set to `TRUE` already in [`com.google.gwt.logging.Logging`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/logging/Logging.gwt.xml).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Another question , if I use simpleRemoteHandler then all the logs are transported to Server side. So at server side should a logging library like log4j should be used to store them conveniently?

Comment: Use the `RemoteLoggingServiceImpl` servlet (mapped to the `/remote_logging` URL pattern), which logs using `java.util.logging`.

Answer (score 4):

In your case to disable the popup -

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
```

You can also configure other details. In our case we go with following

```
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINEST" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler"
        value="ENABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.hasWidgetsHandler" value="DISABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler"
        value="DISABLED" />
```

Comment: I tried enabling only consoleHandler and was expecting that it would show logs to Firebug console also. But it did not. So that means firebugHandler has to be enabled explicitly?

Comment: We have always enabled it. Never checked the other way around :)